# Enable org-mode column-view for nested TODO list by default

Tags: org-mode

I'm trying to setup time estimation in TODO lists via column mode
as describled in http://orgmode.org/manual/Effort-estimates.html#Effort-estimates.
The thing that bothers me is that I have to enable column-view each time to see the columns via org-columns and org-agenda-columns. I would like to add a tag to the head TODO entry and enable the column view for entries with that tag when the file is loaded automatically.
I wonder weather there is some command for that already or something that is related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automatically activate column-view in an *agenda view*, you should try creating a custom view `M-x customize-variable RET org-agenda-custom-commands`.  I *believe* you can set up a view that evaluates an expression using the `settings` element of that configuration.

To default to column-view within an agenda file, you can create a file-local variable – `M-x add-file-local-variable` – that activates the column view:

```
# Local Variables:
# eval: (org-columns t)
# End:
```

This will activate the column view when you load (or reload via `C-c r`) the file.

Caveat: it only seems to honor `#+COLUMN:` properties at the file-level.  I haven't discovered a way to support sub-tree column definitions.  (the `org-column` function has different behavior based on where the point is, so I suppose you could manipulate the point before calling it).